# Problema con clone() jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery

tengo una dificultad, espero que alguien pueda ayudarme. Les comento, estoy trabajando en un modulo html, php, jquery y boostrap, en el cual necesito clonar un input select con jquery y lo hace sin ningun problema, el problema viene cuando intento elegir una opcion de ese select clonado (el nuevo) se elige esa opcion pero del primer select. Ya le cambie id y name pero sigue sin funcionar.

Esta es la funcion que crea el select original:

```
public function input_select($tabla, $id=-1, $cols=12, $campo, $requerido="required", $disabled='' ){
        $modelo = new modelos();            
        $resultado = $modelo->obten_registros_activos($tabla); 
        $registros = $resultado['registros'];
                               
        $label_guion = ucwords($campo);
        $label = str_replace('_', ' ', $label_guion);
        
        $html = "<div class='form-group col-md-$cols' id='contenedor_select_$tabla'>";
        $html .= "<label for='$label'>$label:</label>";
        
        $html .=  "<select name='$campo' $disabled class='selectpicker' data-live-search='true' 
                   title='Seleccione un $label' data-width='100%' id='select_$tabla' 
                   data-none-results-text='No se encontraron resultados' $requerido>";
        foreach ($registros as $key => $value) {                                
            if ($value[$tabla . '_id'] == $id) {
                $selected = "selected";
            } else {
                $selected = "";
            }
            
            $html .= "<option value='" . $value[$tabla . '_id'] . "' $selected>" . $value[$tabla . '_nombre'] . "</option>";
        }
        $html = $html . "</select></div>";
        return $html;
}
```

Y el codigo con el que hago la clonacion es el siguiente:

```
var cont = $(".contador_puestos").val();
var con = parseInt(cont) + 1;
$("#contenedor_select_cat_puesto").clone().appendTo(".contenedor_puesto_"+cont).removeAttr('name').attr('name', 'puesto_'+con);
```

Comment: vale, entendido, ahora espera que pongo la WIJA y convoco a los espíritus para que me pasen tu código y pueda responderte al detalle, o bien, te contesto aquí a tu manera... a ciegas completamente... seguramente tienes algun addEventListener en alguna parte o bien algún cazador de eventos de jquery que te está haciendo la puñeta, búscalo y a ver si lo solucionas. Suerte!

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [ask] y completar el [tour]. Como dice @masterguru, es complicado ayudarte sin poder ver el código, por mucho que te esfuerces en explicarlo.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta pulsando sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece en el pie de la pregunta para agregar la información que falte, gracias

Comment: No, las imágenes de código no ayudan, el código debe ir siempre en modo texto, como lo que has puesto debajo perfectamente bien, pero gracias por el intento. Debes elaborar un [example] que nos permita reproducir tu error y así poder ayudarte del todo bien, pues diría que lo que nos acabas de proporcionar no va a ser suficiente, lo siento, pues me parece que estas cambiando el name de otra cosa y no del select que pretendes clonar, pero no lo puedo probar como no sea tecleando demasiadas cosas, con lo fácil que sería copiarlo y pegarlo de tu pregunta.

Comment: Bueno, más o menos he podido reproducir tu escenario (no estoy del todo seguro aún), pero al hacerlo veo que el name que estás creando lo pones en el div, quedando así: `<div id="contenedor_select_cat_puesto" name="puesto_3">`, lo cual no tiene sentido y no creo que sea lo que pretendes.  Aún así, a mi el select me funciona bien, no veo que me cambie el primer select al escoger una opción del segundo.  Aquí te dejo lo que he hecho para que lo mires:  [Enlace](https://jsfiddle.net/j5rz3ts9/)